# Is it possible to shut off internet via CMD?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, internet

I am wondering if it is possible to shut off a wireless router via computer by typing in a command in CMD?

So for example, if I enter command, the internet goes out throughout the house.

Comment: What is the make and model of the router?  Do you want the entire router to shutdown, or just the internet connection?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your router. Most routers don't directly allow you to shutdown the router in a remote interface. However, if you want to kill the internet, you can release the IP address your router obtained from your Internet Service Provider (ISP), which will stop your internet from working. However, this may not work because your router may be configured to automatically restore the internet/IP address if someone requests something from the internet.

Comment: Like always, it depends on the make and model.